# Unexpected character ' ' (1:0) in node_modules\create-react-context\lib\index.js

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

This keeps happening in create-react-app every time I add a package using yarn.

```
./node_modules/create-react-context/lib/index.js
SyntaxError: d:\project\client\node_modules\create-react-context\lib\index.js: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)

> 1 |
    | ^
```

I have to copy this
https://github.com/jamiebuilds/create-react-context/blob/master/src/index.js
and paste it to node_modules\create-react-context\lib\index.js every time to get rid off that error.

I'm using VSCodium as my editor.
How can I get rid off this error permanently?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling node_modules and re-installing them? Also, you could not use the library, because context has been added to react.

Comment: Yes. I have tried. It's not the first time this happening. I have had to deal with this in another react project.

Comment: is `create-react-context` a package you have installed, or is it a dependency of create-react-context?

Comment: It's a dependency of create-react-app

Comment: do you know what version it is? I am currently seeing 0.2.3 in my latest CRA app. maybe you should try updating the CRA scripts? have you checked the git repo for both CRA and create-react-context?

Comment: It's using 0.2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a permanent solution to this problem. I had to stop working on that project for some reason and since then I didn't face this problem in any other project. In the future if anyone stumbles upon this error this is the temporary solution.

Copy the contents of this file https://github.com/jamiebuilds/create-react-context/blob/master/src/index.js to `node_modules\create-react-context\lib\index.js.`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue on Windows 10 after using `echo > index.js` to create the index.js file. It appears to have inserted characters which were not compatible with the encoding. Just create `index.js` using File Explorer or another editor.